# Why is RIP not scalable?

Tags: routing, ospf, rip

Most of the references say "RIP is not scalable" hence can be used only in smaller networks. But none say "WHY?" What is that in RIP that actually preventing it from scaling to larger networks? And HOW OSPF overcomes the disadvantage of RIP?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Most of the references say "RIP is not scalable" hence can be used only in smaller networks. But none say "WHY?" What is that in RIP that actually preventing it from scaling to larger networks? And HOW OSPF overcomes the disadvantage of RIP?

#### Summary

- [RIPv1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1058) floods routes frequently (every 30 seconds), which introduces large CPU loads as the size of the routing table increases.  This is compounded by the reality that [RIP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1058) recalculates metrics for every route, every time it floods the route out a new interface (regardless of whether there was a topology change or not).  *As the number of routes increases, this is prevents [RIP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1058) from scaling as well as other protocols.*
- [RIPv1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1058) is [classful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classful_network)
- [OSPF](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2328) floods routes infrequently.  If there is a topology change in the network, only the LSAs changed are flooded; metrics are calculated on these changes.  As such, *on-demand route calculations, on [LSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-state_advertisement)s which are flooded infrequently, make [OSPF](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2328) scale well.*
- [OSPF](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2328) is a classless protocol, which supports [CIDR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cidr), which also makes it a more scalable protocol than [RIPv1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1058)

#### [RIPv1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1058) Details:

[RIP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1058) is a [Distance Vector protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance-vector_routing_protocol); all [Distance Vector protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance-vector_routing_protocol)s run the [Bellman-Ford](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman-Ford_algorithm#Applications_in_routing) algorithm.  At a high level, this means:

- All routes in the routing table are periodically announced through all interfaces.
- [RIP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1058) floods routes out every [RIP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1058) interface every 30 seconds.  Since [RIP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1058) routes [by rumor](http://jjrinehart.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/gossip-girlrouting-by-rumor-part-i/), this means every router in the topology must work in direct proportion to the size of the routing table every 30 seconds.  The CPU load and traffic jitter implications of this become scary as you approach thousands of routes (particularly on CPU-based routers with no hardware forwarding).
- The [RIP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1058) protocol itself has a fixed maximum hop-count at 15 hops (which is small if you need to do any form of path-weighting).
- Protocols based on [Bellman-Ford](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman-Ford_algorithm#Applications_in_routing) algorithms are prone to [routing loops](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing_loop_problem), and [count-to-infinity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance-vector_routing_protocol#Count-to-infinity_problem) issues.

#### [OSPF](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2328) Details:

By way of contrast, [OSPF](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2328) is a [link-state protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-state_routing_protocol) running [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm).  As such:

- Each router only announces its *directly connected and redistributed routes* in routing updates (called [LSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-state_advertisement)s).
- Each router floods their own [LSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-state_advertisement) every 30 minutes by default (because the route refresh timer is 3600 seconds, or 1 hour)
- [LSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-state_advertisement)s are also flooded when triggered by changes in the routing table
- Routers use [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) to perform distributed [LSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-state_advertisement) path calculations only when necessary.

Comment: Is there a reason behind comparing RIPv1 to OSPF? Why not compare against v2?

Comment: @fizzle, by convention when someone says RIP, they mean RIPv1; that said, RIPv2 doesn't substantially change RIP's scalability: it introduced classless routing, but it still blasts the full routing table every 30 seconds, and recalculates the table at every hop. If you have ever operated a large RIP network with *flapping links*, you would understand how bad this is... random routing black holes open up and eat good traffic because it takes so long to propagate updates. RIP and RIPv2 have their place, but it's not in a large network.

Comment: Good insight, I've just never seen a network still utilizing RIP. It might be worth mentioning OSPF's ability to authenticate neighbors, although, that doesn't directly answer the OP.

Comment: Thanks @mike-pennington for an answer that is satisfying ;-)

Answer (score 7):

Just to add to what Mike has already explained, RIP recalculates its routes and announces all of them every 30 secs.  In a network with thousands of routers and tens of thousands of routes, that's a LOT of routes being calculated -- the routers would be too busy to actually forward any traffic.

As you probably already learned, RIP's maximum metric is 15 hops.  That limits the size of the network.

RIP has no hierarchy.  Imagine a world-wide network, and every time a link goes up and down in Singapore, the router in Iceland has to recalculate all its routes.  There's no way to isolate one region from another.

Comment: Doesn't the last part (all routers have to recalculate routes) apply to OSPF as well?

Comment: @grawity OSPF has hierarchy, namely areas, which allow you to hide topology changes in one part of the network from affecting other parts.  So if Singapore and Iceland are in different areas, then they don't have to calculate each others routes.